# if else statement with a function jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I've just started to learn jquery and i'm stuck on a certain part, i'm not even sure it's possible as I can't find any answers.

Basically i'm trying to create an if else statement. here's the code I have so far, I know it won't work but i hopefully it gives you an idea of what i'm trying to achieve.

```
if (('.menu').on('click', 'li has:(sub-menu)', function(e))) {
    e.preventdefault();
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').addClass('open');
}
else {
    let link work like normal
}
```

Here's a fiddle of what i'm trying to achieve. http://jsfiddle.net/R6wHG/16/

I can't seem to get the back button working or the final link to it's default.

Comment: Appreciate your learning desire but posting only code doesn't give clear idea, infact your code is not ideal, always post what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this. Pseudocode:

```
$('.menu').click(function(e){
if(has_submenu){
  e.preventDefault();
}
else {
  return true;
}
});
```

Comment: I'v just updated my code (see above) but there's still an issue, check out the fiddle above. Dan